# TypeScript: How to initialise a member of a Generic class that depends on T?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface which defines `MyType` as containing some functions:

```
interface MyType {
  function1(): void,
  function2(): void,
}
```

And a class with a member of type `MyMap` like this:

```
type MyMap<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K][]};

class Example<T> {
  protected _map: MyMap<T>;
}
```

The goal is for Example._var to be a map like this:

```
const var: MyMap<MyType> = {
  "function1" = Function[],
  "function2" = Function[],
```

**Question**

The code below does what it's supposed to do but the compiler complains:

```
// Property '_map' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

I could pass in the map myself like this:

```
    constructor(map: MyMap<T>) {
        this._map = map;
    }
```

But this approach doesn't feel that elegant.

Is there a more concise way to achieve what I want?

**Full code for copy & pasting:**

```
type FunctionRecord<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[keyof T]};
type MyMap<T extends FunctionRecord<T>> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K][]};

class Example<T extends FunctionRecord<T>> {
  protected _map: MyMap<T>;

  constructor(map: MyMap<T>) {
    this._map = map;
  }

  push_to_map<K extends keyof T>(function_name: K, func: T[K]) {
    this._map[function_name].push(func);
  }

  do_for<K extends keyof T>(function_name: K) {
    this._map[function_name].forEach((func) => func());
  }
}

// example implementation:

interface MyHappyType {
  congratulate(): void,
  clap_hands(): void,
}

const happy_map = new Example<MyHappyType>({"congratulate": [], "clap_hands": []});
happy_map.push_to_map("congratulate", () => console.log("Yay"));
happy_map.do_for("congratulate");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the "emptiest" thing that is assignable to `MyMap<MyHappyType>` is `{congratulate: [], clap_hands: []}`.  Those keys are required, so your JS code needs to know the names of the keys and cannot simply instantiate with an empty object.

You can allow `_map` to be an incomplete `Partial<MyMap<T>>` but there are some tweaks that you need to make when properties of `_map` are not guaranteed to be defined.

```
class Example<T extends FunctionRecord<T>> {
    protected _map: Partial<MyMap<T>> = {};

    // helper method ensures that an array always exists
    protected _getArray<K extends keyof T>(function_name: K): T[K][] {
        // initialize if no array yet
        if (!this._map[function_name]) {
            this._map[function_name] = [];
        }
        // circumventing TS error that it could be undefined
        return this._map[function_name] as T[K][];
    }

    push_to_map<K extends keyof T>(function_name: K, func: T[K]) {
        this._getArray(function_name).push(func);
    }

    do_for<K extends keyof T>(function_name: K) {
        this._getArray(function_name).forEach((func) => func());
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/YmpZpw)